# Does Spark SQL use Hive Metastore?

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

I am developing a Spark SQL application and I've got few questions:

1. I read that Spark-SQL uses Hive metastore under the cover?  Is this true?  I'm talking about a pure Spark-SQL application that does not explicitly connect to any Hive installation.
2. I am starting a Spark-SQL application, and have no need to use Hive.  Is there any reason to use Hive?  From what I understand Spark-SQL is much faster than Hive; so, I don't see any reason to use Hive.  But am I correct?

Comment: Spark bootstraps a pseudo-Metastore (embedded Derby DB) for internal use, and *optionally* uses an actual Hive Metastore to read/write persistent Hadoop data. Which does not mean that Spark uses Hive I/O libs, just the Hive meta-data.

Comment: Hello @SamsonScharfrichter I have a case in which I have some inconsistency between `DESCRIBE DETAIL table` and data I retrieve from the `hiveMetastore` db. The case is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60614701/where-is-the-delta-table-location-stored). Do you know how Delta table location is determined?

Answer (score 38):

> I read that Spark-SQL uses Hive metastore under the cover? Is this true? I'm talking about a pure Spark-SQL application that does not explicitly connect to any Hive installation.

Spark SQL does not use a Hive metastore under the covers (and defaults to `in-memory` non-Hive catalogs unless you're in `spark-shell` that does the opposite).

The default external catalog implementation is controlled by **spark.sql.catalogImplementation** internal property and can be one of the two possible values: `hive` and `in-memory`.

Use the `SparkSession` to know what catalog is in use.

```
scala> :type spark
org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

scala> spark.version
res0: String = 2.4.0

scala> :type spark.sharedState.externalCatalog
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.catalog.ExternalCatalogWithListener

scala> println(spark.sharedState.externalCatalog.unwrapped)
org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog@49d5b651
```

Please note that I used `spark-shell` that does start a Hive-aware `SparkSession` and so I had to start it with `--conf spark.sql.catalogImplementation=in-memory` to turn it off.

> I am starting a Spark-SQL application, and have no need to use Hive. Is there any reason to use Hive? From what I understand Spark-SQL is much faster than Hive; so, I don't see any reason to use Hive.

That's a very interesting question and can have different answers (some even *primarily opinion-based* so we have to be extra careful and follow the StackOverflow rules).

> Is there any reason to use Hive?

No.

But...if you want to use the very recent feature of Spark 2.2, i.e. cost-based optimizer, you may want to consider it as `ANALYZE TABLE` for cost statistics can be fairly expensive and so doing it once for tables that are used over and over again across different Spark application runs could give a performance boost.

Please note that Spark SQL without Hive can do it too, but have some limitation as the local default metastore is just for a single-user access and reusing the metadata across Spark applications submitted at the same time won't work.

> I don't see any reason to use Hive.

I wrote a blog post [Why is Spark SQL so obsessed with Hive?! (after just a single day with Hive)](https://medium.com/@jaceklaskowski/why-is-spark-sql-so-obsessed-with-hive-after-just-a-single-day-with-hive-289e75fa6f2b) where I asked a similar question and to my surprise it's only now (almost a year after I posted the blog post on Apr 9, 2016) when I think I may have understood why the concept of Hive metastore is so important, esp. in multi-user Spark notebook environments.

Hive itself is just a data warehouse on HDFS so not much use if you've got Spark SQL, but there are still some concepts Hive has done fairly well that are of much use in Spark SQL (until it fully stands on its own legs with a Hive-like metastore).

Comment: You seem to be contradicting yourself when you say Spark does not use Hive Metastore by default: https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-spark-sql/spark-sql-hive-metastore.html . Also here it says 'Spark will create a default local Hive metastore (using Derby) for you.' http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-load-save-functions.html#saving-to-persistent-tables

Comment: It will only use it if your `SparkSession` was created with `enableHiveSupport` so it's a deliberate choice not a default setting. Spark SQL may or may not use Hive. It's up to a Spark dev.

Comment: @JacekLaskowski , it seems this behavior is different now . As of with spark 2.4.5, spark shell starts the sparksession with inmemory as catalog. How Can in configure to use "hive" instead ?

Comment: A simple command such as spark-shell --conf spark.sql.catalogImplementation=hive
didnt help

Comment: In Spark 3.1.2, you can put `hive-site.xml` in the conf directory, then spark-shell would use hive metastore auto. Make sure you set related configurations in the `hive-site.xml` file.

Comment: Why temp view created via `createOrReplaceTempView` for a Spark using Hive metastore not visible in Hive?

Comment: @SergeyBushmanov Recommend asking this as a separate question. It's an interesting one honestly!

Comment: Found an answer: temp views are short lived objects bound to SparkSession object

Answer (score 3):

It will connect to a Hive Metastore or instantiate one if none is found when you initialize a HiveContext() object or a spark-shell.

The main reason to use Hive is if you are reading HDFS data in from Hive's managed tables or if you want the convenience of selecting from external tables.

Remember that Hive is simply a lens for reading and writing HDFS files and not an execution engine in and of itself.

Comment: Does it do the same for SQLContext object? Where is metadata managed for tables created with SQLContext or SparkSession.sql?