# Spark and Hive in Hadoop 3: Difference between metastore.catalog.default and spark.sql.catalogImplementation

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hive, hive-metastore, hadoop3

I'm working on a Hadoop cluster (HDP) with Hadoop 3. Spark and Hive are also installed.

Since Spark and Hive catalogs are separated, it's a bit confusing sometimes, to know how and where to save data in a Spark application.

I know, that the property `spark.sql.catalogImplementation` can be set to either `in-memory` (to use a Spark session-based catalog) or `hive` (using Hive catalog for persistent metadata storing -> but the metadata is still separated from the Hive DBs and tables).

I'm wondering what the property `metastore.catalog.default` does. When I set this to `hive` I can see my Hive tables, but since the tables are stored in the `/warehouse/tablespace/managed/hive` directory in HDFS, my user has no access to this directory (because hive is of course the owner).

So, why should I set the `metastore.catalog.default = hive`, if I can't access the tables from Spark? Does it have something to do with Hortonwork's Hive Warehouse Connector?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Hey, i got into the same situation. Ddi you get some insights to share ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Catalog implementations

There is two catalog implementations :

- `in-memory` to create in-memory tables only available in the Spark session,
- `hive` to create persistent tables using an external Hive Metastore.

More details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48171845/5198872).

## Metastore catalog

In the same Hive Metastore can coexist multiple catalogs.
For example HDP versions from 3.1.0 to 3.1.4 use a different catalog to save Spark tables and Hive tables.
You may want to use `metastore.catalog.default=hive` to read Hive external tables using Spark API. The table location in HDFS must be accessible to the user running the Spark app.

## HDP 3.1.4 documentation

You can get informations on access patterns according to Hive table type, read/write features and security requirements in the following links :

- [Apache Hive 3 tables](https://docs.cloudera.com/HDPDocuments/HDP3/HDP-3.1.4/using-hiveql/content/hive_hive_3_tables.html)
- [Hive Warehouse Connector for accessing Apache Spark data](https://docs.cloudera.com/HDPDocuments/HDP3/HDP-3.1.4/integrating-hive/content/hive_hivewarehouseconnector_for_handling_apache_spark_data.html)
- [Using the Hive Warehouse Connector with Spark](https://docs.cloudera.com/HDPDocuments/HDP3/HDP-3.1.4/developing-spark-applications/content/using_spark_hive_warehouse_connector.html)